# AngularJS form validation not showing up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I am unable to populate error messages with the following AngularJS form validation code. Its a nested loop where I am trying  to validate the drop down box containing questions and its corresponding answers can be validated. Following is a code sample:

**HTML**

```
<form name="frm" ng-controller="Contract" novalidate>
<div>
  <div ng-repeat="variable in randomQuestionList">
      <div ng-repeat="(key, pair) in variable"> 
          <select style="width:450px" ng-model="selected" ng-options="var.questionDes for var in pair"/>    
            <option value=""> Choose a question</option> 
          </select>
      </div>

      <label for="Answer" >Answer: </label>
      <input type="text" name="answer{{$index}}" ng-model="answers[$index]" ng-maxlength="50" required></input><br>
      <div ng-show="frm.answer{{$index}}.$dirty && frm.answer{{$index}}.$invalid">
        <span ng-show="frm.answer{{$index}}.$error.required"> Answer is a mandatory field. Please enter the answer </span>
        <span ng-show="frm.answer{{$index}}.$error.maxlength"> Maximum 50 characters are allowed </span>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
app.controller('Contract', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        $scope.answers = [];
    $scope.randomQuestionList = 
    [
      {
        "questionList": 
        [
            {
              "questionDes": "What is the first name of the person you first kissed?",
            },
            {
              "questionDes": "Where were you when you had your first kiss?",
            }
        ]
      },
      { 
        "questionList": 
        [
            {
              "questionDes": "What was the name of your elementary / primary school?",
            },
            {
                  "questionDes": "What was your favorite place to visit as a child?",
                }
            ]
          }
       ];
  }]);
```

Comment: could you possibly make a jsfiddle to replicate the problem? and a possible suggestion: put "frm.answer{{$index}}.$dirty &&" in the ng-show of the span instead of a div outside of the spans, and get rid of the $invalid one (since if it causes an error, it'll by default be invalid...its redundant)

Comment: Refer plkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/0K4t8cx4rXsdH5fGrIp5?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This was my approach when I encountered a similar scenario. I used child forms to separate the scope. See if this works for you.

```
<form name="frm" ng-controller="Contract" novalidate>
<div>
  <div ng-repeat="variable in randomQuestionList">
      <div ng-repeat="(key, pair) in variable"> 
          <select style="width:450px" ng-model="selected" ng-options="var.questionDes for var in pair">    
            <option value=""> Choose a question</option> 
          </select>
      </div>  

      <ng-form name="frmChild">
        <label for="Answer" >Answer: </label>
        <input type="text" name="answer1" ng-model="answers[$index]" ng-maxlength="2" required><br>
        <span ng-show="frmChild.answer1.$dirty && frmChild.answer1.$invalid">
          <span ng-show="frmChild.answer1.$error.required"> Answer is a mandatory field. Please enter the answer </span>
          <span ng-show="frmChild.answer1.$error.maxlength"> Maximum 50 characters are allowed </span>
        </span>
      </ng-form>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Working demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qakein?p=preview)

Comment: That seems to have worked. Good part is we dont need to access the $index within the form since the scope of the form gets limited to the child.

Comment: @Intrepid Please mark the answer that helped you most as correct